# How to replace '>> $log_file 2>&1' from all files

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In my files commands are like :

File1.sh:

```
log_file='20210101'
echo -e "\n Output is \n" >> $log_file 2>&1
```

File2.sh

```
echo "Something"
log_file='20210102'
hive -e -f my_file_name.hql >> $log_file 2>&1
```

File3.sh

```
cat myfile
echo "something"
ehco "new line"
log_file='2021-01-01_23_59_59'
hive -e "Select * from tables' >> $log_file 2>&1
```

I am looking for a command to remove the line where defined variable 'log_file' from all the files
AND
remove only '>> $log_file 2>&1' part from all the files

Output in files:

File1.sh:
`echo -e "\n Output is \n"`

File2.sh

```
echo "Something"
hive -e -f my_file_name.hql
```

File3.sh

```
cat myfile
echo "something"
ehco "new line"
hive -e "Select * from tables'
```

I tried multiple ways with sed but nothing worked, few of them are :

I tried :
`sed -e 's/*[>> $]log_file//g' test.sh` 
`sed -e 's/*[>> $]log_file[ 2>&1]//g' test.sh`  
`sed -e 's/\>\> \$log_file \2\>$//' test.sh`  
`sed -e 's/">> $log_file 2>&1"/""/g' test.sh`

Comment: Okay? So what's the problem with just doing that? Having a log file is completely optional. You can simply delete `>> $log_file` and still output all errors and output on `stdout`?

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question is about _a specific problem you encountered_ -- not the thing you're trying to do, but the issue you hit while trying to do it that prevents you from achieving that goal yourself. What did you try, and what problems did you run into in the process?

Comment: I can delete it , but problem is I have more than thousands scripts, so rather than manually deleting it lookin for command which can remove this part from all files.

I tried :
 sed -e 's/*[>> $]log_file//g' test.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` command is a two-step process, and makes a backup of all files (just in case); on my machine (and with the 3 samples you posted) it does the right thing:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^log_file=/d' -e 's/>> \$log_file 2>&1//g' File*
```

Comment: is there any diff with -i  Vs -i.bak ? just want to know for my understanding.

Comment: Absolutely.  `-i` makes the change per file; `-i.bak` makes the change and saved a backup-copy of each file ... with the `.bak` you'll end up with two files, e.g. `File1.sh` and `File1.sh.bak` - the latter having  the original content.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help and explanation to have complete understanding about the command